# Java Brute Force Password Cracker

Tags: java

I am making a brute force password cracker. I am able to use for loops to find which characters match the original password. But the output is not in the correct order. the output is in alphabetical order. How do i fix this?
the output should be something like"

```
z
ze
zeb
zebr
zebra
```

Code:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = "zebra";
    char [] passArr = new char [password.length()];
    passArr = password.toCharArray();

    String brutePass = "";
    char[] alphabet = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p','q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    boolean solved = false;

    while (solved != true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < passArr.length; j++) {
                if (alphabet[i] == passArr[j]) {
                    //brutePass +=passArr[j];
                    //System.out.println(brutePass);

                    StringBuilder forcedPass = new StringBuilder(brutePass);
                    forcedPass.insert(passArr[j], alphabet[i]);
                    System.out.println(forcedPass.toString());
                    solved = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what you expect the output to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your required output, your code should look like this below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = "zebra";
    char [] passArr = password.toCharArray();

    String brutePass = "";
    char[] alphabet = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p','q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    boolean solved = false;
   StringBuilder forcedPass = new StringBuilder(brutePass); // Initialize StringBuilder outside.
    while (solved != true) {
         for (int j = 0; j < passArr.length; j++) { //Moved for loop outside.
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
           
                if (alphabet[i] == passArr[j]) {
                    forcedPass.append(passArr[j]); // Used append instead of insert
                    System.out.println(forcedPass.toString());
                    solved = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I have made two changes, I swapped the position of your inner and outer loop and You have used `insert()` method of `StringBuilder` class, which is incorrect. You have to use the `append()` method of it. To find out more about `StringBuilder` methods,visit [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_stringbuilder.htm).

Comment: this is the correct output thank you. however, I am now realizing that this is infact NOT a brute force password cracker. can you explain why this isnt one and what is this code exactly doing? funny i am asking this since i am the one who made it

Comment: Yes definitely, this is not brute force password cracker. Your code is doing nothing other than just comparing password string's each character to Alphabet's character and when match found just append that character to new String. In brute force, we need to create a password with each possible combination and then check it with original password that whether we got it right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Move the passArr loop outside.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = "zebra";
    char[] passArr = new char[password.length()];
    passArr = password.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder forcedPass = new StringBuilder();
    char[] alphabet = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    boolean solved = false;

    while (solved != true) {
        for (int j = 0; j < passArr.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                if (alphabet[i] == passArr[j]) {
                    forcedPass.append(alphabet[i]);
                    System.out.println(forcedPass.toString());
                    solved = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```